# Jinja2 modal popup (Bootstrap 5) not appearing, no error

Tags: flask, jinja2, bootstrap-modal, flask-wtforms

I've seen a few versions of this question posted but none with exactly the same parameters or with solutions that work for me, so here goes:
within Jinja2 templating, I call a modal-popup in a form, to confirm the shutdown of a peripheral device. The issue is that the modal popup 1. does not display and 2. has not output whatsoever in the terminal or log.

The code for the modal call (last 2 lines in the else):

```
 <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form" style="text-align: center;">
                    {{ power_form.hidden_tag() }}
                    
                    {% if power_status == "None" %}
                    {{ power_form.power_on(class_="btn btn-default") }}
                    {{ power_form.power_cycle(class_="btn btn-default") }}
                    {{ power_form.power_off(class_="btn btn-default") }}

                    {% else %}
                    {{ power_form.power_on(class_="btn btn-success") }}
                    {{ power_form.power_cycle(class_="btn btn-warning") }}
                    {{ power_form.power_off(type="button", class_="btn btn-danger", 
                    data_toggle="modal", data_target="#modalConfirm") }}

                    {% endif %}
                </form>
```

I have checked that the function within Flask allows for both POST and GET calls, and used a default instantiation of the modal according to [Bootstrap documentation.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/) I have also ensured that the required libraries (JQuery, Bootstrap) are requested, and changed the syntax from bs_data_toggle to data_toggle (for trigger as well), neither of which worked.

Please let me know if this is enough information! I am very new to developing for web and would appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks, H.

P.S: Here is the code for the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalConfirm" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalConfirmLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalConfirmLabel">Shutdown Confirmation</h5>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S (2): The relevant CSS / JS inclusions.
Within head, here are the CSS includes:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/spectrum.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Within a separate block of scripts after the body are the JS includes:

```
 <script src="{{ url_for('static', 
  filename='js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript"> 
 </script>
 <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/core/popper.min.js') }}" 
 type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/core/bootstrap.min.js') 
 }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Could you also include the HTML source of the modal popup?

Comment: Hello again Dauros! Absolutely, added it to the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included the Bootstrap v5 library, but accidentally used the v4 syntax (and documentation) for the modal. There's was a [change in the new version](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#usage): the `data` attribute got a `-bs-` suffix (not a prefix). So we have to use e.g. `data-bs-toggle` HTML attribute to pass the information to Bootstrap:

```
{{ power_form.power_off(type="button", class_="btn btn-danger", 
                        data_bs_toggle="modal", data_bs_target="#modalConfirm") }}
```

Comment: Thank you, just fixed the syntax here, but it seems the issue is related to something else.

Comment: Then there's a different issue, I just copy-pasted your code with the fixed data attributes and it's working fine. Are you sure that `power_status` is not `"None"`, therefore you are in the `else` branch, so you add the required attributes to the button? If you open the browser's development terminal, do you see any JS error?

Comment: The power_status is definitely None (I have a print statement to monitor this in the terminal). The other buttons work fine and report terminal output, but pressing power off has zero output whatsoever. Perhaps it might be an issue with the Bootstrap version I have included? I have added this to the main post.

Comment: If `power_status` is `None` then your power off button does not have the required BS attributes to activate the modal: `{{ power_form.power_off(class_="btn btn-default") }}`. You only added them in the `else` branch's power button. Set the `power_status` to something to have have the working power off button in the `else` branch. In the first, `power_status == "None"` case, your power off button should be having the 'disabled' state (so the user cannot click on it), since it does nothing there.

Comment: Hi Dauros, sorry for the confusion here - the power_status is None, but it does not trigger the None clause of the if statement due to a separate issue relating to peripheral flags. This can be seen in the system by logging into the portal, where the buttons having colors (instead of being assigned as btn-default, or grey). As such the issue must be something else.

Comment: Well, if the red (`btn-danger`) power off button in the `else` branch still doesn't open the the modal window, then I'm out of ideas. Maybe you should check the generated source code to ensure everything is ok, or put a button with the corresponding attributes manually somewhere. And also make sure there's no JS error in the browser dev console.